# How to fix 'mongod[10993]: Error reading config file: No such file or directory' in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm having a problem setting up my MongoDB Database for my Flask App, do you guys know how to fix this?

I've already tried to reboot and reinstalled it.

```
● mongodb.service - MongoDB Database
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; 
 vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2019-08-03 01:43:03 
 PST; 5s ago
 Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Process: 10993 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config 
 /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 10993 (code=exited, status=2)

 Aug 03 01:43:03 linux-ubuntu-robert-terminal systemd[1]: Started 
 MongoDB Database.
 Aug 03 01:43:03 linux-ubuntu-robert-terminal mongod[10993]: Error 
 reading config file: No such file or directory
 Aug 03 01:43:03 linux-ubuntu-robert-terminal mongod[10993]: try 
 '/usr/bin/mongod --help' for more information
 Aug 03 01:43:03 linux-ubuntu-robert-terminal systemd[1]: 
 mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, 
 status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
 Aug 03 01:43:03 linux-ubuntu-robert-terminal systemd[1]: 
 mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it is a bit old, but I had the same problem on Linux Mint 19.2.

To solve it I have created the config file '/etc/mongod.conf' according to the [documentation - Configuration File Options](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/).
The content copied from Windows, where it was automatically created by installation.

```
# mongodb.conf

# Where to store the data.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log

logappend=true

bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
#port = 27017

# Enable journaling, http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Journaling
journal=true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu = true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true
#auth = true

# Verbose logging output.
#verbose = true

# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
# developing drivers)
#objcheck = true

# Enable db quota management
#quota = true

# Set diagnostic logging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#diaglog = 0

# Diagnostic/debugging option
#nocursors = true

# Ignore query hints
#nohints = true

# Disable the HTTP interface (Defaults to localhost:27018).
#nohttpinterface = true

# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
# functionality
#noscripting = true

# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.
#notablescan = true

# Disable data file preallocation.
#noprealloc = true

# Specify .ns file size for new databases.
# nssize = <size>

# Accout token for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-token = <token>

# Server name for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-name = <server-name>

# Ping interval for Mongo monitoring server.
#mms-interval = <seconds>

# Replication Options

# in replicated mongo databases, specify here whether this is a slave or master
#slave = true
#source = master.example.com
# Slave only: specify a single database to replicate
#only = master.example.com
# or
#master = true
#source = slave.example.com

# Address of a server to pair with.
#pairwith = <server:port>
# Address of arbiter server.
#arbiter = <server:port>
# Automatically resync if slave data is stale
#autoresync
# Custom size for replication operation log.
#oplogSize = <MB>
# Size limit for in-memory storage of op ids.
#opIdMem = <bytes>

# SSL options
# Enable SSL on normal ports
#sslOnNormalPorts = true
# SSL Key file and password
#sslPEMKeyFile = /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
#sslPEMKeyPassword = pass
```

After saving the configuration file just restart mongodb service:

```
sudo systemctl restart mongodb
```

Comment: i dont understand why some mongod.conf files are in the above format (which works) and others are in the YAML format (which never works)